# Не работают динамические стили Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Гружу динамические стили через настройки wordpress, код вывода стилей выглядит так

```
<php function zm_live_styles() {

    $zm_main_color = get_option('zm_main_color');

    echo "

<style type='text/css'>

.overlay {background-color: $zm_main_color;}


</style>";

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'zm_live_styles'); ?>
```

Почему то сам стиль не применяется. Все файлы подключены, но в консоли отображается только `.overlay {background-color: ;}`. Если в background-color написать какую-нибудь ересь, то все отображается. Какая-то проблема в переменной может быть $zm_main_color? Другие настройки работают, кроме того при настройке сайта в самом кастомайзере все изменения в динамике видны, но во фронтэнде ничего не видно. Как такое может быть?

Comment: перед echo сделайте var_dump($zm_main_color); и посмотрите что приходит. Скорее всего null возвращается из get_option

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' в дебаге

Comment: Я понял в чёт у Вас ошибка! У Вас код начинается с `<php`, а должен с `<?php` раз такую ошибку выдает debug

Comment: Вместо echo надо использовать return